# Email table width is to small for the description

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, html-email

I am trying to send a automated report mail with following table, but the width of the columns is far to small for the description fields and I have no idea why this is not adjusting.

I have already tried

```
   width: auto;
   width: px;
   width: &;
   width: 1px;
   white-space: nowrap;
```

Table:

```
    <h1>E-48<h1>
    <table stlye='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; border-collapse: collapse;
white-space: nowrap; table-layout:fixed;'><tr>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'></td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Spinner temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Front bearing temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Pitch cabinet blade B temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Pitch cabinet blade C temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Blade A temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Blade B temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Blade C temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Rotor temperature 1</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Rotor temperature 2</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Stator temperature 1</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Stator temperature 2</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Nacelle ambient temperatur</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Rear bearing temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Nacelle temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Nacelle cabinet temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Rectifier 1 heat sink temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Rectifier 2 heat sink temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Rectifier cabinet temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Excitation heat sink temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Ambient temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Tower temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Control cabinet temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Transformer temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Inverter 1 cabinet temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Inverter 2 cabinet temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Pitch heat sink blade A temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Inverter 3 cabinet temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Pitch heat sink blade B temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Pitch heat sink blade C temperature</td>
    <td style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 100%;'>Pitch cabinet blade A temperature</td>
```

Comment: I didn't get your question??

Comment: the text in of the table headers is wraped (displayed in 3-4 rows).

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout
"Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can speed up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but subsequent cell content may not fit in the column widths provided."
Your first table row is empty.

Comment: still not working. I also have implemented the code from my console to http://s430135357.online.de/index.html  here it is working, but not in the mail

Comment: from the link above:
h1 isn't closed 
there's no closing table tag </table>
lot of closing </textarea> without opening tag <textarea>
check your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a width to your table. `<table width="100%"...`